# after removed WorkerManager in new build app geting crash

Tags: android, android-asynctask, worker, jitpack

getting crash after removed extends to `Worker` class in new build

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.MyWorker cannot be cast to androidx.work.ListenableWorker
```

i changed to

```
public class Mywoker extends Worker {}
```

to

```
public class Mywoker {}
```

getting above crash any help appricaited